# Handle Exceptions in node/express not working

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node/express application which I'm trying to catch all exceptions so that the application doesn't just freeze. I created an error by calling a mongoose db when it's not running.

```
await mongoose.connect(dbUrl, mongooseOptions);
```

Which gives me the following error then the app crashes

> MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on
> first connect

Before that is run, I have the following:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (ex) => {
    console.log(ex.name, ex.message);
    console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...');

    process.exit(1);
});
```

That unhandled Rejection doesn't seem to run. How can I get it to run on exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`uncaughtException`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception) instead of `unhandledRejection`

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', (ex) => {
    console.log(ex.name, ex.message);
    console.log('UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION!  Shutting down...');

    process.exit(1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the diff? And shud I be doing both?

Comment: You should yes and the difference is `The uncaught exception` vs `The object with which the promise was rejected (typically an Error object)`